# conditional scope based on either two fields being true but not both

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am needing to create a scope that checks for either two fields on the model being true, however it shouldn't include records where both are true, only ones where either of them are. I hope that makes sense.

I am using Rails 3.2 and Mongo 3. Can any recommend a way to achieve this?

My first attempt has been

```
scope :with_training_complete, where(
:volunteer_training_completed => true
).or(:face_to_face_training_attended => true)
```

but that brings back only records where both are true.

any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `scope :with_training_complete, where("volunteer_training_completed = true OR face_to_face_training_attended = true")` - can you try this ?

Comment: @dkp i get the following error `Mongo::OperationFailure: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Comment: what you want is an exclusive or : (p AND NOT q) OR (q AND NOT p). You can build that with mongo using `$and`, `$or` and `$not` query operators

Comment: @VonD but im sure you cant do that within a rails scope as that is what I need unfortunately.

Comment: @DMH http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13294860/using-a-combination-of-ands-and-ors-in-mongoid

Comment: @VonD managed to build a query from that response. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get what I want from VonD's comment. This led me to create:

```
scope :with_training_complete, where( :$or => [ { :video_training_completed => true }, { :face_to_face_training_completed => true } ])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are suppose to use `^` for this.

This will explain what it does:

```
irb(main):002:0* a
=> 1
irb(main):003:0> a ==1
=> true
irb(main):004:0> b=2;
irb(main):005:0* (a==1) && (b==2)
=> true
irb(main):006:0> (a==1) ^ (b==2)
=> false
irb(main):007:0> (a==1) ^ (b==3)
=> true
irb(main):008:0>
```